# Warhammer 40K game

Tags: story-identification, video-games, warhammer-40k

I saw a brief clip of a WH40k being played in a Youtube short clip. However, the uploader of the video did not say what game it was. The clip was of a FPS game and showed the player character engaging in a boss fight against what I presume is some servant of Nurgle as one of the enemy's lines is just repeating "*Seven*". As the boss fight starts, the player gets an objective pop-up saying "*Deliver the Emperor's Judgment*". What game is that scene from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Games_Workshop_video_games - I count about ten FPS games in total. It's probably easiest to just look at each one until you find the right one.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSMJt_VuHqI / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvqEmRiF6As

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Warhammer: 40,000 - Darktide](https://www.playdarktide.com/).

One the the tasks you're given is to;

> "***Deliver the Emperor's Judgement!***"

[image]